Color conversions formulas
I need formulas to convert betwen color spaces, is there official color conversion reference or something of this kind? I can't find it with simple google search.
rgb -> hex,
rgb -> hsl,
rgb -> cmyk,
rgb -> xyz
...
Yes I know i can find this on web, my question is are there official formulas somewhere, or at least at one place?

Let us first understand each of the models.
In RGB (typically used in displays), we use the combination of Red, Green and Blue components (in that order) to specify any color. Typically, the intensity (contribution) of each color component is represented as an integer between $0-255$ ($8$ bits), where $0$ means absence and $255$ means $100\%$ presence of that color. Thus, Black will have the RGB code $(0,0,0)$, White $(255,255,255)$, Red $(255,0,0)$, Magenta $(255, 0, 255)$ and so on.
The hex notation (typically used  in coding) is just another representation of the RGB model. Each of color components are written in $8$-bit binary code and thus represnted by hex $2$-digits (thus total $6$ hex digits). Typically, we also prepend a $\#$ symbol before the color value. The Hex code for Black is $\#000000$, White $\#FFFFFF$, Magenta $\#FF00FF$ and so on.
CMY  (typically used in print media) is a complementary colorspace of the RGB model and uses Cyan, Magenta, and Yellow as its primary colors. The idea is that Cyan denotes absenece of Red and $100%$ presence of both Green and Blue, hence its color code is $(0,255,255)$ or $\#00FFFF$. Similarly, Magenta is $(255,0,255)$ or $\#FF00FF$ and Yellow is $(255,255,0)$ or $\#FFFF00$. Other colors can also be represented similarly. You can read more about the color wheel for a better visualization. In CMYK we additionally allow blacK color to be mixed subtractively, and has practical advantages). Here's how you can convert from RGB to CMYK:
Black   = minimum(1-Red, 1-Green, 1-Blue)
Cyan    = (1-Red-Black)/(1-Black)
Magenta = (1-Green-Black)/(1-Black)
Yellow  = (1-Blue-Black)/(1-Black) 

In HSL (typically used in computer vision and image analysis), we use Hue, Saturation, and Lightness (luminescence, brightness, or intensity value). A top-down view (from the L axis) of the color space will basically give the classical color wheel of the RGB/CMY model. Roughly, Hue denotes the angle on the color wheel, Saturation denotes the radius on that, and Lightness denotes how bright or dark the color wheel we have chosen. The coversion between RGB and HSL is a bit involved, so I am putting links instead of replicating the same: wiki, stackoverflow.
The XYZ model (typically used for objective comparison of colors) refers to CIE 1931 color space. There are different models other than the CIE 1931 one. For this also, I am leaving pointers:
physics.stackexchange, stackoverflow, stackoverflow.
PS: In most popular programming languages, such as Python, MATLAB, etc., you would find libraries/toolboxes for such conversions.

I know there are innumerable websites that tell you that CMYK = 1 − RGB, and even offer helpful JavaScript conversion tools, but they're all completely wrong. If that were true there would be no reason for CMYK to exist. The reality is that RGB systems are for lights, CMYK systems are for inks, there are many variants of each, and converting between them is complicated.

Color is complicated and can't be summarized in a list of formulas for the most part.
Of the strings of letters you mentioned, the only ones that denote specific, unambiguous color systems are "xyz" (CIE XYZ) and "hex" if it means the hexadecimal color codes used on web pages, which are always sRGB. The sRGB article that I just linked explains how to convert it to and from XYZ.
There are many different RGB, CMYK, and HSL color systems. Converting between any variant of RGB and CMYK is very complicated because TVs and other emissive displays behave very differently from ink on paper. When you see "HSL" in some paint program's color picker, it's usually a trivial transformation of sRGB (or some other RGB space), but every program has its own implementation, which may or may not work as described in Wikipedia's HSL and HSV article. There are also more sophisticated standardized HSL systems like CIELCh. That article explains how to convert it to and from XYZ.
